# How to maintain spacing between the bubbles in bubble chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created bubble chart using the layout.pack
and graphs is rendering fine on initial load and on updating it.

But i am facing issue in keeping x amount of distance from each other(bubbles)

i have a screen area of 1000px still the bubble chart are forcefully clubbing together in small area and the distance between the bubble are of 5-10 px max.

Is there any way to increase the distance between the bubbles, I tried putting padding (of pack layout) but it shrinks the radius of the bubble to create the spacing which makes the circle very small.

Whats needs to be done in that case?